# Firebase Auth v9: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need help, i was watching tutorial for firebase and react. and then i realised the tutorial was for v8
and the newest one is v9

this is my firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getDatabase } from "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  //firebaseconfig
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const database = getDatabase(app);

export { auth, database }
```

and then this is my signin.js snippet code

```
import { auth, database } from "../Firebase/firebase";

const submitForm = async (values) => {
   
auth()
.signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email,values.password)
.then((userCredentials) => {
        props.history.push("/profile");
      }).catch((err) => {  
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

and then when i submit my form the application crash with error
on auth().

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { auth, database } from "../Firebase/firebase";
// this  ^^^^ is not a function but is being used as one
// auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email,values.password)
// ^^^^ here
```

`signInWithEmailAndPassword` needs to be imported from `firebase/auth` as shown below:

```js
import { auth, database } from "../Firebase/firebase";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"

const submitForm = async (values) => { 
  const userCredentials = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, values.email, values.password)
  // Pass the 'auth' instance here                         ^^^^
  const { user: { uid } } = userCredentials
  console.log(`userId: ${uid}`)
}
```

I'd recommend following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) along with any tutorial. The documentation has both name-spaced (v8) and modular/functional (v9) syntax.

Comment: thank you for the fast response, i've tried this and it seems i read the wrong ones. thanks !!